# 2nd Order Inhomogeneous Recurrence Relation with Cosine

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I got the following homework in university:

> Solve with the ansatz-method:
>   $$a_n - a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} = \cos (\frac {n \pi } 3)$$

So I solved the characteristcal equation $\lambda^2 - \lambda + 1$ and got the homog. solution
$$x_n^{(h)} = r^n ( C_1 \cos ( \phi ) + C_2 \sin( \phi ))$$
with $r=1$ and $\phi = \frac \pi 3$.

Now I struggle with the particular solution.
I tried to use the following ansatz:
$$A \cos( \frac {n \pi} 3 ) + B \sin ( \frac {n \pi} 3 ) $$
But when I plug that into the given equation I get:
$$A \cos (\phi_n) + B \sin (\phi_n) - A \cos (\phi_{n-1}) - B \sin (\phi_{n-1}) + A \cos (\phi_{n-2}) + B (\sin \phi_{n-2}) = \cos (\phi_n) \\\text{with } \phi_n = \frac {n \pi} 3$$
This brings me nowhere.

**Where did I go wrong?** And how do I solve this properly?

Comment: Your ansatz has the same form as the homogeneous, which will result in $0$ when plugging it in. You'll need to make a different guess

Comment: I am so ignorant... You are right. So I have to multiply by n and then it should work? But how? I still cannot equate the coefficients...

Comment: I believe it should. Try again with the ansatz $$ a_n = n(A\cos n\phi + B\sin n\phi) $$ and update the question to show us what you got. You can use trig identities to simplify things like $$ \cos (n+1)\phi = \cos \phi \cos n\phi - \sin \phi \sin n\phi$$ and so on

Comment: Ok, tomorrow... Going to sleep now. #mathOnSunday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The homogeneous solution has the form

$$ {a_n}^{(h)} = c_1\cos (n\phi) + c_2\sin (n\phi) $$

with $\phi = \pi/3$

For the particular, you'll need the ansatz

$$ {a_n}^{(p)} = n\big(A\cos (n\phi) + B\sin (n\phi)\big) $$

Using some trig identities, you can simplify the recurrence terms
$$ \begin{align} 
a_{n-1} &= (n-1) \Big(A\cos\big((n-1)\phi\big) + B\sin\big((n-1)\phi\big) \Big) \\
&= (n-1) \Big(A\cos \phi \cos (n\phi) + A\sin \phi \sin (n\phi) + B\cos \phi \sin (n\phi) - B\sin \phi \cos(n\phi) \Big) \\
&= \frac{n-1}{2}\Big( (A - \sqrt{3}B)\cos (n\phi) + (\sqrt{3}A + B)\sin (n\phi) \Big) \\ \\  
a_{n-2} &= (n-2) \Big(A\cos\big((n-2)\phi\big) + B\sin\big((n-2)\phi\big) \Big) \\
&= (n-2) \Big(A\cos (2\phi) \cos (n\phi) + A\sin (2\phi) \sin (n\phi) \\ 
&\qquad\qquad\quad + B\cos (2\phi) \sin (n\phi) - B\sin (2\phi) \cos(n\phi) \Big) \\
&= \frac{n-2}{2}\Big( -(A + \sqrt{3}B)\cos (n\phi) + (\sqrt{3}A - B)\sin (n\phi) \Big)
\end{align}
$$

And then some more algebra to obtain the $\cos(n\phi)$ and $\sin(n\phi)$ coefficients.

Good luck.